# Problem with deleting items from pivot table

Tags: php, sql

I am building project for learning purposes in oop php where I create properties/ads, and I have three tables, properties, photos and property_photo. My goal is when I click on delete button to delete properties at the same time to remove those photos that are connected to properties through pivot table, but when I try that I only delete properties from properties table and photos and ids in pivot table remain in database. I'm having difficulties writing sql query in my model. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

AdModel.php

```
public function deleteProperty($id)
{
    $this->db->query('DELETE FROM properties WHERE id=:id');
    $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
    if ($this->db->execute()) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
}

public function deletePropertyPhoto($id)
{
  $this->db->query('DELETE FROM photos WHERE id=:id;
  DELETE FROM property_photo WHERE photo_id=:photo_id AND property_id=:property_id');
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
  $this->db->bind(':photo_id', $id);
  $this->db->bind(':property_id', $id);
  if ($this->db->execute()) {
    return true;
  } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

AdsController.php

```
public function addeleteAction()
 { 
    $this->Auth->isLoggedin();
    $this->Auth->isAdmin($_SESSION['user_id']);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $this->Auth->isSet($_GET['id'], "ads/index");

          if ($this->AdModel->deleteProperty($_GET['id'])) {
            $photo = $this->AdModel->deletePropertyPhoto($_GET['id']);
            if ($photo != false) {
              if (file_exists('public/photos/' . $photo->photo)) {
                unlink('public/photos/' . $photo->photo);
              }
            }
            redirect('ads/index');
          }
          echo "User is not found!!!";
     } 
 }
```

Comment: You have to describe your model, otherwise will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @SamuelTeixeira What info do you need, because my model is big and I don't know what code to put that is relevant.

Comment: The FK or relation between photos, property_photo and properties.

Comment: photos (id, name, extension, created_at, updated_at),   property_photo (id, property_id, photo_id),   properties (id, title, description, type_of_property, use_of_the_property, quadrature, location) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete from photos:

```
DELETE FROM photos 
where photos.id in (select photos.id FROM photos join property_photo   
where property_photo.property_id = :property_id);
```

After that:

```
DELETE FROM property_photo WHERE property_id=:property_id
```

Comment: Now I get this error  'Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' . I know that this is problem with bind() bellow query I just can't get it right. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you remove the other binds? Now you only need the $this->db->bind(':property_id', $id); isn't ?

Comment: yes, I did exactly that, and now it says that I have yntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN property_photo on (property_photo.photo_id=photos.id) WHERE property_'   I just can't seem to find error

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/join-syntax/ this is the error in the syntax of your db , try with join only , instead inner join

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194815/discussion-between-samuel-teixeira-and-marko).